# using conditional IF statements in arm templates for properties,

Tags: azure, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a situation where I want to only add a property to a VM if a condition is met. For example if I want to add an availability set property to a machine then do this : Below I ONLY what to execute the availability set statement if a condition is TRUE, can you do this in an ARM template? eg if a value is true then do this line, if not skip?

```
 {
  "name": "[parameters('ComputerName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('1stNicName'))]",
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('2ndicName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('ComputerName')]"
  },

  "properties": 

{
"availabilitySet": {
      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
    },


 "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "[parameters('serverVmSize')]"


 },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerName": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
      "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
    },
```

Answer (score 11):

As of this week (1st August 2017), ARM templates now have an IF function that can be used for variables, properties and resource parameters. It works like most other ARM functions, with syntax like:

```
[if(condition, true value, false value)]
```

The [example in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical) does exactly what you are asking, adds (or doesn't add) an availbility set to a VM:

```
"apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "properties": {
                "availabilitySet": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilitySet'),'yes'), variables('availabilitySet'), json('null'))]",
                ...
            }
```

Note that the True value, the availiblity set to use, is stored as a variable rather than inline in the if statement.

```
"variables": {
    ...
    "availabilitySetName": "availabilitySet1",
    "availabilitySet": {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',variables('availabilitySetName'))]"
    }
},
```

Comment: That's great, very useful ... will try that. ManyThanks

Comment: I don't think the tooling has been updated yet to support it, but this shouldn't cause you any issues with running it, I certainly have had no problems doing so. If you get an error when you run it  then it maybe it hasn't rolled out to your region yet, test in West Central US as it is definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing this. you can use conditional to choose a value, but you cannot not set a value or pass in `null` (unless you want to define 2 variables for `properties').

so you can just define 2 vm resources that are exactly the same except for the property in question (so `availabilitySet`). One would have it and the other one would not. And you would use `"condition": expression` in both resources. Condition should equals to `false` or `true` to work. There are several functions in ARM templates that can evaluate input and return `true` or `false`.

Reference:
https://samcogan.com/conditions-in-arm-templates-the-right-way/

Comment: so, just to be clear, there is no way of placing conditions on properties of a resource only on the resource deployment itself?

Comment: yes, exactly. @itye1970 which I find extremely annoying

Comment: makes no sense. this is just a repost of official documentation in other words. nothing is coming in this field any time soon. @SamCogan

Comment: @4c74356b41 If you'll notice, that's my blog post, and what I was subtly hinting at was that perhaps you might want to keep an eye out for some new information coming soon that might help you out.

Comment: highly doubt that, never heard about new features in arm templates coming out any time soon. @SamCogan

Comment: This is what I was ever so subtly trying to hint at - https://samcogan.com/dynamic-arm-templates-with-inline-logic-operators/

Answer (score 0):

```
"variables": {
    "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
      {
        "id": "[parameters('lbBackendAddressPool')]"
      }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe i have found a workable way to avoid defining two entire VM definitions for an availability set. following are from my own testing in an arm template i have made with extensive conditional controls.

this works:

```
"availabilitySet": {
  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets',parameters('availabilitySetName'))]"
}
```

this does not:

```
"availabilitySet": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilitySet'),'yes'), variables('availabilitySet'), json('null'))]",
```

this also does not work due to ID being 'null':

```
"availabilitySet": {
  "id": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilitySet'),'yes'), variables('availabilitySet'), json('null'))]"
}
```

I have added the following variable and parameter:

```
"parameters": {
"SpotInstance": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false,
            "allowedValues": [
                true,
                false
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Should the VM be deployed as a low cost Spot Instance, this will deploy without attaching the Availability Set."
            }
        }
},
"variables": {
"AvailibilitySet": {
            "On":{
                "id":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/',variables('ASName'))]"
            },
            "Off":"[json('null')]"
        }
    }
```

then used this logic on the availability set assignment:

```
"availabilitySet": "[if(equals(parameters('SpotInstance'),bool('true')),variables('AvailibilitySet').Off,variables('AvailibilitySet').On)]",
```

if you do not define id as a property of "AvailabilitySet" this can be null, if you Do however it cannot be null.